# Can't get user location with iOS MapKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, mapkit

Getting the user location to work has been killing me...

I've read lots of threads explaining the new changes with iOS 8 and how there must be one of two keys (`NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` or `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`) in the info.plist file in order for the app to ask permission to get user location. I did that.

[image]

I've also included what *I believe* as all the code needed for the location service to work...but it doesn't. Please see my mapViewController.h and mapViewController.m files below:

**mapViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MKAnnotation.h>

#define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)

@interface mapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property(nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end
```

**mapViewController.m**

```
#import "mapViewController.h"

@interface mapViewController ()

@end

@implementation mapViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
    if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
        // Use one or the other, not both. Depending on what you put in info.plist
        //[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
#endif
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    [self.mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [self.mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [self.mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];

    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; //Whenever we move
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"%@", [self deviceLocation]);

    //View Area
    MKCoordinateRegion region = { { 0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
    region.center.latitude = self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
    region.center.longitude = self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.005f;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.005f;
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 800, 800);
    [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];
}
- (NSString *)deviceLocation {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"latitude: %f longitude: %f", self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
}
- (NSString *)deviceLat {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude];
}
- (NSString *)deviceLon {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
}
- (NSString *)deviceAlt {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", self.locationManager.location.altitude];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Also, in case this is relevant, the mapViewController is tied to a tab in a Tab View Controller. When I click on the tab that includes the view controller containing MKMapView, I get the below image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and run the application in device to get the current location.
If you run in simulator, then it will show the default location i.e Apple Inc's address as current location.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
  [self.locationManager setDelegate:self ];
  self.mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;
  [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation: (CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
  [self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:newLocation.coordinate animated:YES];
  MKCoordinateRegion   region=MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(newLocation.coordinate,70000 ,70000 );
  MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [self.mapView regionThatFits:region];
  [self.mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
}
```

Note:
 Turn on data or wifi in your device, or else you will face Location Accuracy error.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code to your ViewController.h class,

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property(nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@end
```

And in ViewController.m class ,

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
[super viewWillAppear:animated];



}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the docs, `[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]` is asynchronous. Implement the location services auth changed delegate callback and start monitoring there only after the auth status is allowed.